# Eclipse ran TwitchBot just stops without error

Tags: java, eclipse, irc, twitch

I made a TwitchBot that I have been running for a long time, and every now and then it would just terminate itself. (Stop running).
I assumed these were internet or connection drops but it's happening a lot more often today. Does anyone have an idea what could cause it and how to debug it in the future?

What it looks like after it stops itself:
[image: Issue]

Chat log at time of termination:
[image: Twitch Log]

There is nothing that is being specifically ran on any of those messages. So I have no way of specifically try-catching a throwable. 
Unless I made it try catch on an onMessage listener so it checked every chat message that is seen. - Other than that, there is no reason there should be a hard coded error.

I use TwitchIRC API if anyone thinks it may be something within the API.
https://github.com/lmariscal/twitchirc

EDIT:

Just happened again whilst writing this:
What it looks like after it stops itself:

[image: Issue]

Comment: sounds like https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/bot-disconnecting/8278 are you responding with pongs to the pings and such?

Comment: @Tschallacka yes the API does this automatically (https://i.gyazo.com/628b52b35cbdb03cc0c2345bdf5e051e.png) - After reading the post you linked, he fixed it by forcing a re-connect if there was no PING/PONG. However, I would not be sure where to start with that... :/